# A problem on multi-variable calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:R^n \to R $ be a C¹ function and let $\vec{c}:R \to R^n$ be a C¹ path which solves the differential equation, $ \vec{c}'(t)=-\nabla F(\vec{c}(t))  ,t\in R $.
(a) Show that $f(t)=F(\vec{c}(t))$ is a non increasing function of t.
(b)For any t for which $\nabla F(\vec{c}(t)) \neq \vec{0}$ show that $\vec{c}$ is a smooth path and f(t) is strictly decreasing in t.

Answer (score 0):

You have a gradient dynamical system, which evolves along the gradient of $-F$. For part $(a)$ just observe
$$
f'(t)=\nabla F(c(t))\cdot c'(t)=-c'(t)\cdot c'(t)=-|c'(t)|^2\le 0.
$$
For part $(b)$, just observe that your condition is equivalent to $c'(t)\neq 0$, which is the regularity condition. In that case $f'(t)=-|c'(t)|^2<0$ and $f$ is strictly decreasing at that $t$.